# Application crashing when I try to play audio file using swift

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

```
func playCorrectSound() {
    let soundURL: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("correct", withExtension: "m4a")!
    correctSound = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundURL)
    correctSound.play()


}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if correctIncorrectField.text == answerField.text && correctIncorrectField.text != "" && answerField.text != "" {
        pointsNum = pointsNum + 10
        points.text = "\(pointsNum)"
        textField.text = ""
        textField.hidden = true
        correctIncorrect.hidden = false
        correctIncorrect.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        correctIncorrect.text = "Correct!"
        pauseAndDoStuff()
        playCorrectSound()

    }
    if correctIncorrectField.text != answerField.text && correctIncorrectField.text != "" && answerField.text != "" {
        pointsNum = pointsNum - 5
        points.text = "\(pointsNum)"
        textField.text = ""
        textField.hidden = true
        correctIncorrect.hidden = false
        correctIncorrect.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        correctIncorrect.text = "Incorrect!"
        pauseAndDoStuff()
    }
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

For some reason its crashing on the

```
let soundURL: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("correct", withExtension: "m4a")!
```

line and its only saying:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that `correct.m4a` file is exist in your project

and It is included in `Copy Bundle Resources` in `Target -> Build Phases`

[image]